# Run jQuery function on resize if condition is met

Tags: jquery

I am trying to run a script that will show a message when hovering over my logo. I only want this to run on screen sizes larger than 768.e.g not mobiles. The div will appear and show a random message from a list.

On resize I check if my content container is equal or larger than 692, and if it is I add a class hoverInfo to the body. I only want to run the script if this class exists, yet the script still runs regardless.

Currently I run the script on doc.ready, but run the script to check the width on window resize and doc.ready.

Any help would be really appreciated!

```
$(function(){
    function checkWidth() {
        if ($('#content-wrap').width() == 692) {
            $('body').addClass('hoverinfo');        
        } else {
            $('body').removeClass('hoverinfo');
        }   
    }
    checkWidth();

    $(window).resize(function () {
         setTimeout(checkWidth, 200);
    });

    function showText(){
        $randomText = $(".page #messages");
        $(".hoverinfo #logo").hover(
            function () {   
                $randomText.show();
            },

            function () {
                $randomText.hide();
            }
        );              
    }       
    showText();                 
});
```

Comment: First of all you do not need the $(document).ready since $(function is equivalent, so you can either remove the "ready" or replace both $(function wrappers with a single one. Also, what do you mean by "only if the class exists?" Exists in the body or has been defined?

Comment: Thanks for your response. My site is responsive, so if the width of the container is 692 or more (my standard ipad and desktop layout) I want to add a class, hoverInfo, if it is smaller, It will remove it from body. It isn't defined in the markup, only happens on doc ready once I have checked the width.

Thanks for the heads up on the doc ready.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think hover works as a live event in jquery. So will set itself and stay for the rest of page load.

Try;

```
        $(".no-touch .page.hoverinfo #logo").on("mouseenter", function(){
            $randomText.show();
            var aux=hoverText($text);
            $(".page #messages li:eq("+aux+")").show(); 
            $("#logo").css('opacity','1');
        });

        $(".no-touch .page.hoverinfo #logo").on("mouseleave", function(){
            $randomText.hide();
            $text.hide();
            $("#logo").css('opacity','1');
        });
```

Also, I think you have a typo;

```
if ($('#content-wrap').width() == 692) {
```

Should be;

```
if ($('#content-wrap').width() >= 692) {
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately that hasn't resolved the issue. The script works fine on desktop widths, but when resizing it smaller it doesn't work. The hover messages still display.

If I refresh at 320px the script works, but then resizing back up adds the correct class but doesn't rerun the hover script

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to have a css rule that dictates what screen sizes that message is allowed to be seen on. Maybe wrap your text content inside of a div like so

```
<div class="showOnLrg">
<h3 id="randomText" style="display:none;"></h3>
</div>
```

then in your stylesheet have a rule with a media query

```
.showOnLrg{display:none;}
@media screen and( min-width : 768px){
.showOnLrg{display:block;}
}
```

That way you can hide and show the text using jquery on hover function without having to check screen resolution in your resize function, in fact you wouldn't need a resize function. Yes your hover function will fire, however if the parent container of the text is hidden, you won't see the text when you toggle it. so you can just declare your hover function like so.

```
$(".hoverinfo #logo").hover(
            function () {   
                $randomText.show();
            },

            function () {
                $randomText.hide();
            });
```

If you are set on doing it within the resize function, shouldn't you be looking at the window size and not the div size?

```
$(window).width();
```